# Codeigniter 404 on valid routes when using custom htaccess mod rewrites

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

Im having an issue with codeignighter when using custom (somewhat strange) htaccess folder mapping. However, it should technically work, but it does not. Can someone help me?

---

**Scenario 1 (Works Fine):**

Folder structure and key files

```
/ is the website root
/.htaccess
/api/ <this is the CodeIgniter Root, with index.php and default CI .htaccess>
```

/.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ /api/$1 [L]
```

accessing mydomain.com/api/admin/ for example gets me to my admin-controller/index action and loads the views fine.

var_dump on index.php for $_REQUEST shows

```
array (size=1)
'admin/' => string '' (length=0)
```

---

**Scenario 2 (Does not work):**

Folder structure and key files

```
/.htaccess
/current/.htaccess
/current/api/ <this is the CodeIgniter Root, with index.php and default CI .htaccess, this is the same folder/files/htaccess as above scenario>
```

/.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /current/$1 [L]
```

/current/.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ /api/$1 [L]
```

**accessing mydomain.com/api/admin/ for example gets me to the Codeigniter 404 Page/view.**

var_dump on index.php for $_REQUEST shows (Same as Scenario 1)

```
array (size=1)
'admin/' => string '' (length=0)
```

---

What is going on here? I know the htaccess rewrites are strange, but as far as what Codeigniter sees, the route is the same (admin/). But they both behave differently. Why? I tried everything i could think of, as far as i can see, codeigniter sees the right path as far as the Request Object goes, but the CI router somehow does not use it correctly.

Any help appreciated, let me know if you can think of anything i can try to help debug this further.

Note: the reason im using double htaccess is so that i can schedule different instances of CI depending on time/scenario (you can use rewrite condition to serve different folders instead of the "current" folder). Im currently not using this, so in scenario 2, the root only has the one "current" folder.

Comment: try this `RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ /api/index.php/$1 [L]`

Comment: What about any asset files within the api folder? as its common with codeigniter, what about api/assets/mylogo.jpg? Any requests for that would then go into the codeigniter php files and would come as a 404. Am i wrong?

Comment: Just to clarify, the api folder also contains a htaccess file, the usual CI htaccess file: http://pastebin.com/aHM9cjtr as mentioned on the question

Comment: when you call mylogo.jpg with in your php file it will not through error? but if you type in url then it will through error. So it  act as hotlink protection

Comment: i think you do not understand the point. i require everything within the api folder to work as it should. Linking to pages within CI, linking to images, or what ever other assets that are present. I think you are completely missing the point of the question. ps. in this scenario with your solution, "hotlink protection" is a Bug not a Feature.

Answer (score 2):

Removing index.php from the URI at CodeIgniter can be a pain. Last week I was confronted to a similar case: I have my root web directory at `/var/www/html` and inside `/ci` my project... so inside `/ci` I have the following .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

and in the apache2 config file I added the following:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/ci/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Also check that in `application/config/config.php` you have:

`$config['uri_protocol']    = 'REQUEST_URI';`

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

You're redirecting the requests to a folder, while in fact you should be redirecting these to index.php file of CodeIgniter.

e.g:

```
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ /api/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

That is assuming you have 'index_page' set to empty string in your config file, If it's set to index.php, then when requesting something you should be including index.php in the url.

Comment: What about any asset files within the api folder? as its common with codeigniter, what about api/assets/mylogo.jpg? Any requests for that would then go into the codeigniter php files and would come as a 404. Am i wrong?

Comment: Just to clarify, the api folder also contains a htaccess file, the usual CI htaccess file: http://pastebin.com/aHM9cjtr as mentioned on the question

Comment: You have already defined it, !-f & !-d which means, if something that isn't a file or isn't a directory requested it will go through the index.php file of codeigniter. which means you should be able to request your assets the normal way.